# Customizer Changeset, Sidebar and Rest API Custom Endpoints

Tags: rest-api, theme-customizer, headless

How can I get rendered sidebar content with REST API inside a WordPress Customizer Changeset ( customize_changeset_uuid )?

Related to this question:

> The customizer should be able to point to a headless frontend to preview, as long as the frontend looks for the customize_changeset_uuid query param and passed it along in any REST API calls, while also including the customize-preview.js file.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/12/customize-changesets-technical-design-decisions/

Comment: How are you rendering the sidebar content when not inside the Customizer?

Comment: @JacobPeattie returning dynamic_sidebar echo with Custom Endpoints. I am open to a different suggestion